# running python apps in powershell

Tags: android, python, windows, powershell

Every time I try to run the command > `python ./build_android.py` I receive the error message saying that python is not recognized as a cmdlet.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python and double checking that I was in the correct location, but everything checks out, any suggestions about what's wrong?

Comment: If Python is installed correctly you can simply run `.\build_android.py`.

Comment: Make sure the python executable is in your path, and that its actually named python (and not python.exe).

Comment: @GabeSechan: I'm pretty sure it _should_ be named `python.exe` or it won't even run at all. In fact, it may even be `Python.exe` or `PYTHON.EXE`; PowerShell, like cmd, will find any of those when you try to run `python`. This is Windows, not Unix.

Comment: @GabeSechan what a.....python can be named python.exe and i can just type python and it would works. It's not linux, it's Windows and it's acceptable on that platforms for exe and com extensions

Comment: I meant that if it has.exe, he has to adjust his command accordingly

Comment: @GabeSechan: No, he doesn't. On Windows, in both PowerShell and cmd, if you type `python`, it looks for anything that's a case-insensitive match to `python.exe`, `python.com`, `python.cmd`, and a few other extensions. It is not only acceptable, but idiomatic and correct, to just type `python`.

Comment: @GabeSechan no, exe is not a case, python is just not in the PATH variable

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot, but have you tried restarting since you installed python?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have Python added to your path.

I'm not sure what version of windows you are on, but you need to locate the advanced systems settings in control panel, click environmental variables and append `;C:\pythonXX`to your Path system variable, where `XX` is your python version. It might be `27` or `34`.

Comment: This is unnecessary to run Python scripts on Windows. The .py extension should be associated with either the default interpreter or (preferably) the new py.exe launcher that executes the initial shebang line. Shebangs can point at a real executable (e.g. `#!C:\Python27\python.exe`) or can be virtual (e.g. `#!python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`).

Comment: thanks for responding! I'm running windows 7 enterprise with python 2.7.  While I understand what you're trying to get me to do, I'm afraid I don't really get how to do it.  My control panel doesn't contain anything seemingly similar to what you're describing

Comment: @questionable The advanced system settings should be located in the system section of the control panel. One easy way of navigating there is to press the windows key and the pause key simultaneously. The link to the advanced system settings should be in the left hand menu.